# Does rafatha in Quran equals dirty talking?

Tags: nikah, tafseer, arabic

In [two places](https://corpus.quran.com/qurandictionary.jsp?q=rfv#(2:187:5)) Allah (SWT) talks about رَفَثَ.

And [almaany.com](https://www.almaany.com/ar/dict/ar-ar/%D8%B1%D9%81%D8%AB/) defines it as کلام قبیح among other things.

But I am not Arab and I don't understand its true meaning.

Does this mean *dirty talking*?

Is it a permission given by Allah to spouses to have dirty talking with each other?

Comment: The link you refer to actually provide an answer of your question neither of both mean dirty talk, but in one instance  it refers to intercourse and in the other it indicates  nikah. While you have chosen rafath in the context of speech.

Comment: @Medi1Saif, which link? If you mean the link to Quran, then I'm trying to understand the etymological meaning of the word *rafatha* which means that I have to refer to an Arabic dictionary.

Comment: No I'm referring to the link from al-Maany. As stated your chase is one special case which is related to speech while the general case is related to the pleasure men seek when looking for women, so it is either legal intercourse if they are married already or nikah if they intent to get married. Maybe a hint why it is regarded as dirty talk in a context because it was not usual nor of good manners to talk about intercourse openly, it was rather done by hints as you may often encounter in the Quranic text

Comment: In the Quran, *Nikah* as a word exist. *Bashiruhunna* also exists. So, logically it should be another thing. Also, this word in Arabic dictionaries has a meaning that is very specific. I know that we can't force meanings upon Quran, but we can't also interpret it as we wish. After all, Quran claims that it's in clear Arabic. And it seems that Arabs use that word to refer to stuff that is considered dirty to be said in public.